# submitting form values to meteor method but get error userSchema not defined

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm trying to create a Meteor method to save the user profile from a form created by autoform.  I'm getting an error saying the userSchema is not defined.  It is defined in my helper which is within a Meteor.isClient condition, which could be the problem.  I tried making it available to both the client and server but that didn't work.

What I'm trying to acheive is simply take the form values and insert them into the Meteor.users.profile.

Looks like the server isn't seeing the userSchema which is visible on the client.

I'm getting this error:

> I20140816-14:14:28.170(-7)? Exception while invoking method 'saveProfile' ReferenceError: userSchema is not defined
>   I20140816-14:14:28.173(-7)?     at Meteor.methods.saveProfile (app/server/server.js:6:16)
>   I20140816-14:14:28.173(-7)?     at maybeAuditArgumentChecks (packages/livedata/livedata_server.js:1487)
>   I20140816-14:14:28.173(-7)?     at packages/livedata/livedata_server.js:643
>   I20140816-14:14:28.173(-7)?     at _.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:56)
>   I20140816-14:14:28.174(-7)?     at packages/livedata/livedata_server.js:642
>   I20140816-14:14:28.174(-7)?     at _.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:56)
>   I20140816-14:14:28.176(-7)?     at _.extend.protocol_handlers.method (packages/livedata/livedata_server.js:641)
>   I20140816-14:14:28.176(-7)?     at packages/livedata/livedata_server.js:541

My Schema:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {

Schema = {};

Schema.UserProfile = new SimpleSchema({
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        regEx: /^[a-zA-Z-]{2,25}$/
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
        regEx: /^[a-zA-Z]{2,25}$/
    },
    gender: {
        type: String,
        allowedValues: ['Male', 'Female']
    },
    bio: {
        type: String,
    },
    avatar: {
        type: String,
    },
    pinCode: {
        type: Number,
        min: 7,
        max: 7
    },
    phoneNumber: {
        type: Number,
        min: 9,
        max: 10
    }
});



Schema.User = new SimpleSchema({
    _id: {
        type: String,
        regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Id,
        optional: true,
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Email,
        optional: true,
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        optional: true
    },
    profile: {
        type: Schema.UserProfile,
    },
    services: {
        type: Object,
        optional: true,
        blackbox: false
    }
});
SimpleSchema.debug = true;
Meteor.users.attachSchema(Schema.User);

}
```

Here's my helper:

```
Template.signupForm.helpers({
  users: function () {
   return Meteor.users;
  },
  userSchema: function () {
   console.log('returning user schema')
   console.log(Schema.User)
     return Schema.User;
  }
});
```

My Meteor method (server.js):

```
Meteor.methods({
  saveProfile: function(doc) {
   console.log('Meteor method 1')
    // Important server-side check for security and data integrity
    check(doc, userSchema);

    console.log('Meteor method')
    console.log(doc.firstName)

  }
});
```

My template

```
<template name="signupForm">
 <div class="panel-body">
   {{#autoForm schema=userSchema id="signupForm" type="method" meteormethod="saveProfile"}}
  <fieldset>
    {{> afObjectField name='profile'}}
  </fieldset>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Insert</button>
  {{/autoForm}}
</div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please apply 2 steps :

1 : 
Add `Schema` object (wih all descendants) to dir (like folder both) where it will be visible for client and server.

2 :
On server side use **Schema.User** instead **userSchema**.
Note that **userSchema** is defined on client side in `Template.signupForm.helpers` and because of that `Meteor.methods.saveProfile`  cannot find it.